# btrfs two Data sections and enospc error when trying to convert

Tags: raid, btrfs

I currently have a btrfs filesystem setup like this:

```
# btrfs fi df /storage/

Data, RAID1: total=2.33TiB, used=2.32TiB
Data, RAID0: total=2.00GiB, used=2.00GiB
System, RAID1: total=32.00MiB, used=340.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=4.00GiB, used=2.53GiB
```

and:

```
# btrfs fi show

Label: none  uuid: 5e63e5b5-48bb-442e-a79c-1c71a22de476
    Total devices 3 FS bytes used 2.33TiB
    devid    1 size 2.73TiB used 1.56TiB path /dev/sda
    devid    2 size 2.73TiB used 1.56TiB path /dev/sdd
    devid    3 size 2.73TiB used 1.55TiB path /dev/sdc

Btrfs v3.12
```

As you can see I have two data sections, one with most of my data in RAID1 and another one, 2GiB large, with RAID0 configuration. I want to end up will all of my data in RAID1.

I have tried balancing the whole /storage/ filesystem, I have tried, as suggested in another question, the command `btrfs balance start -dprofiles=raid0 -dconvert=raid1  /storage/` to convert just the raid0 part to raid1. However, this is the result:

```
# btrfs balance start -dprofiles=raid0 -dconvert=raid1  /storage/
ERROR: error during balancing '/storage/' - No space left on device
There may be more info in syslog - try dmesg | tail
```

Checking the syslog as suggested yields:

```
[432205.142548] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered. 
[480205.124621] btrfs: relocating block group 4968366997504 flags 9
[480205.286706] btrfs: 1 enospc errors during balance
```

Comment: Please [report this problem on the btrfs mailing list](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs_mailing_list). I did wrong calculation, sorry. I agree that you should have about twice the usable space in your configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have found a solution since then. But for all those still looking (like I was 15 min ago) here is an answer (source: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Balance_Filters see balancing when file system full)

You need to perform a balance without conversion and using a low value for the usage filter:

```
btrfs balance start -dusage=0 /storage/
```

Then you can try to increase the number for usage (e.g. -dusage=10).

Finally you should be able to start your balance with conversion.

See the source for all background explanations.